# ¿Cómo obtengo con un array solo 1 dato en PHP?

Tags: php

En MySQL tengo una tabla `membresia` con los siguientes campos:

- id_membresia
- nombre_membresia
- precio_membresia

Y hago una consulta en PHP de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php 
  include('configuracion/inicio_conexion.php'); 

  $result = $mysqli->query("select * from membresia");

  while($resul=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $var=$resul[0];
    $var1=$resul[1];
    $var2=$resul[2];

    var_dump($var);
  }
?>
```

Necesito obtener solo el `precio_membresia` para dejarlo en el `input`:

```
<input type="text" name="precio" value="<?php $precio1 ?>">
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Hola ¿Podrias colocar el código que estas intentando? para comprender mejor lo que estas queriendo hacer.

Comment: En ese código da la sensación que falta el fetch, no te olvides de poner el SQL de la tabla además del PHP que te sugiere @M.Gress

Comment: subi otra imagen donde cambie lo que hice pero me trae solo el id

Comment: Cuelga el código en modo texto y el SQL de la tabla y te lo miramos

Comment: listo no se si esta bien hay como lo deje... espero que se entienda

Answer (score 1):

Si solo necesitas ese campo con modificar tu consulta, debería bastar:

```
select precio_membresia from membresia
```

O, como veo que tienes:
id_membresia, nombre_membresia, precio_membresia

Respetando ese orden tu variable sería $var2, en cuyo caso esa es la variable que tendrías que poner en tu input:

```
<input type="text" name="precio" value="<?php $var2 ?>">
```

Comment: en mi campo precio tengo 3 datos quiero tener esos datos separados lo que me dices no me sirve :/

Comment: bueno pero en ese caso no modifiques la consulta, era en caso de que SOLO necesitaras ese campo, y como te decía si $var2 es la que guarda el precio_membresia, esa es la que tiene que ir en tu input para que te muestre el valor

Comment: Si no te sirve es porque tu pregunta esta mal planteada. Haces referencia a que solo necesitas un dato y eso es lo que te da esta solución. Si luego necesitas los otros datos eso queda fuera de la pregunta.